# Как можно понять что слово является тем словом которое нужно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим `а = "те*т" #тест`
И мне нужно чтоб если `а` был в списке в котором есть `тест` срабатывал оприделенный код, можно конечно по очереди заменять каждый символ на `*` и потом проверять, но это слишком долго и не надежно, у меня есть код который в каждом слове сначала убирает повторяющиеся буквы чтоб срабатывать на `теест`, затем меняет все символы по очереди на `*`, и сравнивает есть ли эти слова в листе, но такой код работает очень долго и не еффективно
Есть ли варианты лучше?

Comment: Имею серьезные подозрения что это не возможно без нейроннки, но она будет требовать много озу, а у меня на сервере всего 1гб, а свободно там сейчас около 250мб

Comment: Почитайте про расстояние Левенштейна https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings

Comment: Как-то у вас немного сложно написано, но разве регулярные выражения не решат вашу проблему?

Comment: Я лично ничего не понял. Нужно больше примеров.

Comment: Мне просто нужно понимать что строка слово в переменной `а` похоже на слово из листа

Comment: @Сергей нет не решает

Comment: @mazik7512 спасибо, это то что нужно

Comment: А, ну тогда https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz хотя приведённая @mazik7512 выше ссылка имеет много хороших ответов, можно выбирать любой для начала